# python HTTP response data in XML

Tags: python, xml

I have a HTTP request Get which I know it's response data looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestSpec xmlns="TestSpec.xsd">
  <Tests>
    <TestCase>
      <TestCase>abc</TestCase>
    </TestCase>
  </Tests>
</TestSpec>
```

I am trying to retrieve it's data so I can validate, the response data which is g0

```
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree=etree.fromstring(g0.text.encode('utf8'), parser)
```

How can I get those data I ahve tried

```
    print ("\ntree= "+ str(tree.TestCase))
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `g0.text.encode('utf8')` is returning the example XML string you gave, then you shouldn't need to use the HTML parser. Try something like this:

```
tests = etree.fromstring(g0.text.encode('utf8'))[0] # Notice the "[0]" here

for testCase in tests.findall("{TestSpec.xsd}TestCase"): # Notice the namespace here
    print(testCase[0].text)
```

In the code above, I used `[0]` to get the 0th (first) child of the root element, which is the `<Tests>` tag. The for loop uses `findall` which returns all of the children directly under the `Tests` tag that match the given tag name. Notice that I included the namespace from the top level `<TestSpec>` tag in brackets ahead of the tag name. In this case `findall` returns all of the outer `<TestCase>` tags. Inside the loop I used `[0]` again which is the first child of the `<TestCase>` tag; in this case, the inner `<TestCase>`. Finally `.text` is the attribute that contains "abc".

This will work for XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestSpec xmlns="TestSpec.xsd">
  <Tests>
    <TestCase>
      <TestCase>abc</TestCase>
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase>
      <TestCase>def</TestCase>
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase>
      <TestCase>ghi</TestCase>
    </TestCase>
  </Tests>
</TestSpec>
```

But not like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestSpec xmlns="TestSpec.xsd">
  <Tests>
    <TestCase>
      <TestCase>abc</TestCase>
      <TestCase>def</TestCase>
      <TestCase>ghi</TestCase>
    </TestCase>
  </Tests>
</TestSpec>
```

In which case you would need to use `findall` or some other means of iterating instead of hardcoding the `[0]` for the first child. Something like this:

```
for outerTestCaseTag in tests.findall("{TestSpec.xsd}TestCase"):
    for innerTestCase in outerTestCaseTag.findall("{TestSpec.xsd}TestCase"):
        print(innerTestCase.text)
```

Same goes for the first `[0]` to get the `<Tests>` tag. I'm sure there is some better "pythonic" loop comprehension to improve that nested loop, but that is the general idea.

Comment: My situation is the 2nd you wrote above so I tried [0] it didnt work

Comment: Thank you I managed to get it working with your help, tests = etree.fromstring(g0.text.encode('utf8'))[0] # Notice the "[0]" here

for testCase in tests.findall("{TestSpec.xsd}TestCase"): # Notice the namespace here
    print(testCase[0].text)  is the answer as it turns out then --> testCase[1].text  is next line